# User d-bus service post-start/pre-stop

Tags: linux, systemd, d-bus

I need to run a script AFTER systemd has started the user `dbus.service` and run another script BEFORE systemd attempts to stop `dbus.service`. I don't want to modify the existing service files. The script is supposed to save and restore the loaded CDEmu images across reboots. The global service that called cdemu with `--bus system` has stopped working a few years ago, because in modern distros each user has their own set of loaded virtual images.

My current solution is having two user services: the `-pre.service` `WantedBy=dbus.service` and the `-post.service` that `Requires=dbus.service`

The latter is auto-stopped along with `dbus.service`. The first service must be enabled manually for each user who wants it. It starts the second service by launching `systemctl start` in background to avoid deadlock. Also, the first service stops immediately after start to properly handle dbus restart.

I want to know whether it's possible to reduce the number of services to just one, possibly with `StopWhenUnneeded`.

For testing I exit the X session and do:

```
$ systemctl --user stop dbus
$ systemctl --user start dbus
```

_

```
# /etc/systemd/user/dbus-pre.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dbus-hook pre-start
# will be started again when dbus restarts
RemainAfterExit=false

[Install]
# systemctl --user enable dbus-pre
WantedBy=dbus.service
```

_

```
# /etc/systemd/user/dbus-post.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dbus-hook post-start
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/dbus-hook pre-stop
# oneshot supposed to spare dbus until ExecStop finishes
Type=oneshot
# RemainAfterExit=true prevents immediate stop of our service
RemainAfterExit=true

[Unit]
# Requires= supposed to stop us when dbus stops
Requires=dbus.service
# After= supposed to spare dbus until our service stops
After=dbus.service
```

_

```
#!/bin/bash
# /usr/local/bin/dbus-hook
echo "$1"
case $1 in
    pre-start)
        echo "starting dbus-post.service..."
        /usr/bin/systemctl --user start dbus-post.service >/dev/null 2>&1
        ;;
    post-start)
        echo "restoring cdemu mounts..."
        if [ -f ~/.config/cdemu.save ]; then
            {
                read -r x
                read -r x
                while read -r n b f; do
                    if [ x"True" = x"$b" ]; then
                        /usr/bin/cdemu load "$n" "$f"
                    fi
                done
            } <~/.config/cdemu.save
        fi
        ;;
    pre-stop)
        echo "saving cdemu mounts..."
        #echo "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS"
        if /usr/bin/pgrep -u "${USER:?}" -x cdemu-daemon >/dev/null; then
                mkdir -p ~/.config
            /usr/bin/cdemu status >~/.config/cdemu.save
        fi
        ;;
esac
```